# How can i change timezone data Python

Tags: python, django

```
istanbul = timezone('Europe/Istanbul')
created_at = "Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012"
dtt = created_at.replace(tzinfo=istanbul)
xnxx = time.mktime(time.strptime(str(dtt),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Error : unconverted data remains: +01:57

Comment: What do you mean by unconverted data?

Comment: its my error @LaszloPapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [pytz doc](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/). There is really only one way to change timezones. You have to use `localize` and `astimezone`.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
istanbul = pytz.timezone('Europe/Istanbul')
created_at = datetime.strptime("Wed Aug 29 17:12:58 +0000 2012", 
                               "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %y")
pytz.utc.localize(created_at).astimezone(istanbul)
```